# Any recommendations for viewing source files inside a .tgz file?

Tags: bash, haskell, gzip, tar, cabal

Haskell's `cabal` package manager stores recent package source code in `~/Library/Haskell/repo-cache/*/*.tgz`  I've found that one often wishes to refer to Haskell module source code as documentation.

I'm happy simply using `zless` for small mostly text packages, but I could easily imagine improving upon this workflow.

I could install `go` to use `zipfs` from [`go-fuse`](https://github.com/hanwen/go-fuse) to mount frequently referenced `.tgz` file directly, which might be useful.  Anyone seen a fuse utility that mounts multiple .tgz files on one mount point?

I could alternatively write a `tarless` utility that treated a `.tgz` file like a directory by unpacking it in `/tmp` and displaying the file that appears after the `*.tgz/`.  I'd then build the `bash` tab completion to navigate `.tgz` files from the command line.

Does anyone have recommendations in this or similar directions?

Comment: Nice question, but it might be slightly more suitable for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but as far as I know you can open/edit/save changes to `.tar.gz` files directly with vim and emacs (and probably with other editors).

Comment: I'd envisioned a command line solution, but that's perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

zcat or gzcat works reasonably well with `.tgz` files for me on Mac.

Comment: btw you can do same with `gunzip -c file.gz` also.

Comment: For me zcat or gzcat or gunzip -c behave differently from zless on Mac as zless shows lots of funny non-printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

[AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) is a FUSE filesystem that presents a filesystem view where each archive has an associated directory (at least for read-only access). The view of the filesystem is conventionally mounted on `~/.avfs`, and the directory associated with an archive has a `#` at the end.

```
mountavfs
ls ~/.avfs$HOME/Library/Haskell/repo-cache/foo/bar.tgz\#
```